# recover pictures from upload folder in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a damaged WordPress site, there is a lot of important gallery. so I want delete all WordPress file except upload folder and install new WordPress. so do you have any solution to recovery my picture from upload folder in new WordPress?
my mean from recovery is Reconnoiter all files in upload folder to new WordPress!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy everything from `http://yourdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/` to some local folder via FTP.